# UFT not closing / exiting programmatically post test run

Tags: testing, vbscript, automated-tests, hp-uft

I am running Automated test suite in UFT which is invoked via a VB script. Issue is that post test run, VB script is not able to close UFT programmatically.

VB Script:

```
Dim Test_path
Test_path = Script_Name
On Error Resume next
Dim qtApp 'As QuickTest.Application ' Declare the Application object variable
Dim qtTest 'As QuickTest.Test ' Declare a Test object variable

Set qtApp = CreateObject("QuickTest.Application") ' Create the Application object

qtApp.Launch ' Start QuickTest
qtApp.Visible = True ' Make the QuickTest application visible

' Set QuickTest run options
qtApp.Options.Run.RunMode = "Fast"
qtApp.Options.Run.ViewResults = False
qtApp.Open Test_path, True ' Open the test in read-only mode

' set run settings for the test
Set qtTest = qtApp.Test

'set result settings
Set qtResultsOpt = CreateObject("QuickTest.RunResultsOptions") 
qtResultsOpt.ResultsLocation = Location

' Run Tests
' THIS IS WHERE I TELL UFT TO RUN TESTS
' AND THE CONTROL NEVER COMES BACK TO VB SCRIPT
' UFT RUNS TESTS AND STAYS IDLE
qtTest.Run qtResultsOpt

qtTest.Close
qtApp.quit
```

I am running the VB script from the command line and the handle never comes back to the command prompt.

Any idea how can I make UFT to close once tests are executed?

Comment: If I comment out the test run `qtTest.Run qtResultsOpt`, then the VB script runs fine, the control comes back and VB closes UFT successfully.

Comment: Is the Location correct?

Comment: I meant Location in this statement - qtResultsOpt.ResultsLocation = Location.  Your script seems to be correct logically. I do not see any issues here. This is what i too have. 1 more question...does the qtp test runs fine? but it does not close the test once it is run. is that rt?

Comment: Yes, the Location is correctly pointing to the correct path, and the results are indeed getting generated at this Location. And yes, the tests run fine, but it doesn't closes UFT post test run and VB script keeps running indefinitely.

Comment: Comment this 'On Error Resume next' statement. Check if it throws an error while closing the test. Because qtTest.Close is supposed to close. if it does not close, it might throw some run time error. On Error Resume Next simply hides the error.

Comment: Did that. UFT reports no error. Tests run fine. BUT, the control never comes back to VB (only when tests are run) and following lines of code are never executed - `qtTest.Close
qtApp.quit`

Comment: still no luck, huh?   
Can you try this plz? - 'qtTest.Run Nothing'  instead of 'qtTest.Run qtResultsOpt'.  Does it help to close the QTP test once the run is over?

Comment: Have you checked to make sure that your test is actually finishing? For example, is there still a process running in the background that tells the VBScript that the test is still running, and as a result doesn't ever actually execute `qtTest.Close`? Add a msgbox after `qtTest.Close` and see if that gets executed.

Answer (score 0):

Try to Set qtApp nothing after closing or quitting if no response , if you want to get the handle back to the command line , you can use appActivate method of wscript.shell object using window name. Hope this help

Answer (score 0):

Because this line

```
qtTest.Run qtResultsOpt
```

is still not done (maybe your Run is loop in a test to call another tests, i guess ), so you cannot break it to next line.

Try to break your script into two of .vbs files. One of them do launching QTP & running, the another one is your main script will call it and do something else.

```
Dim objShell
Set objShell = Wscript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
objShell.Run "..\LaunchAndRunQTP.vbs"
Set objShell = Nothing
```

Hope it help.